# How to using lambda to gather elements which has the same index in multiple lists in java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm now using Java8,

what I want to do is to pick the elements from different list by the  element's index in each list

I have follow code:

```
List<List<Integer>> lst = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7),
            Arrays.asList(2, 5, 8),
            Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9)
    );
```

I want the output would like:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I tried but didn't get the result. So would you please give me some hint?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post the code you used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it creating the `IntStream` of list indices and mapping them. The following code solves your problem (assuming input list is non-empty and every row have the same number of values):

```
List<List<Integer>> transposed = IntStream.range(0, lst.get(0).size())
    .mapToObj(idx -> lst.stream().map(l -> l.get(idx)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```